# Programmatically change UIButton size - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a simple iOS application which is using the Google Plus iOS SDK. I want to customise the sign in button. I have managed to get it looking how I want, but I can't get the button to be the size I want. (I am not using auto layout). Here is my code in my viewDidLoad:

```
[addservice_4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiTagFriendsAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addservice_4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiTagFriendsAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[addservice_4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiTagFriendsAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
addservice_4.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
addservice_4.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
addservice_4.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
```

Doing the above changes programmatically leaves me with this end result:

[image: UIButton screenshot]

As you can see the button is too wide. So I tried change its size programmatically but that does not work either:

```
addservice_4.frame = CGRectMake(20, 22, 101, 30);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Anyone know anything?

Comment: I'm guessing here because I haven't used the SDK, but you might try changing the size of the button in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method of the ViewController that contains the button.

Comment: If that button uses autolayout then changing frame doesnt matter. Does it use autolayout?

Comment: @AlexReynolds Nope I am not using Autolayout.

Comment: Actually I just turned on Autolayout and it worked! Because I think the constraints stops the Google Plus SDK from making the button bigger. Still Autolayout is a complete pain :(

Answer (score 0):

if you have to set the image property on `UIButton` Apple recommends using an image with the right size or double its size if using image assets.

if that's not a good option for you, I guess you could get the setFrame: method to work as you'd expect in your question by using the setBackgroundImage:forState instead of setImage:forState like this:

```
[addservice_4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiTagFriendsAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addservice_4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiTagFriendsAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[addservice_4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiTagFriendsAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
addservice_4.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
addservice_4.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
addservice_4.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
addservice_4.frame = CGRectMake(20, 22, 101, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Autolayout in the end turned out to fix the problem (because I believe the constraints it puts in place stop the Google Plus SDK from making the button bigger). The only problem is that I now have to fix a mirage of other problems like support for 3.5 inch display and so on because Autolayout is truly horrible.... :(